# Company domain google site visitors by name via google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a company domain google site and enabled google analytics account. Could somebody advice if it is possible to view same domain site visitors by name?
I want to track who of my colleagues visited my site and what is the frequency.

Thanks.

Comment: You technically could, but you are not allow to pass personal information such as names into Google Analytics by its Terms of Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to connect a user in Google Analytics to a person, you'd need some sort of system to make the connection. This could be a login, a form, a url parameter, or something like that, where at a certain point you know who they actually are. At that point, you can assign them an ID (in a custom dimension) and make reports tracking their behavior.

It is worth noting (as above) that you can't store personal info in Google Analytics - so the ID would have to be non-identifying, like a GUID or random, numerical ID.

*Some strategies for connecting website users to individuals include:*

**Email Marketing** - Many email marketing companies allow you to pass a unique identifier in the URL of anything they click. You could then read this url parameter with javascript and assign it to a custom dimension in Google Analytics.

**Login/SignUp** - You might have some content behind a login-wall. For example, in order to download a document, you make the user fill out some personal information (like an email and their name), then email a link to the document to them. Once you have the user's information in your system (via the form submission), you can grab the user's ID from the submission.

**Manual Parameter** - Similar to the "Email" one, you could just email your colleagues a link to the website with a custom ID on each link. Just read that parameter from the URL with javascript and assign it to a custom dimension.